# Why am I getting 'Unreachable Code' error in Go for loop

Tags: go

I've got a three component for loop that iterates over a Policies struct, which holds a list of Policy types, which is also a struct. However, in the for loop, the 'i++' is highlighted and apparently unreachable. I'm not sure why? Because when I run the application, it does actually execute the c.sendResultDialog function, so it is reachable, but I don't know why this error is showing up.

```
for i := 0; i < len(policies.Policies); i++ {
        if strings.ToLower(c.name) == strings.ToLower(policies.Policies[i].PolicyName) || strings.ToLower(c.name) == strings.ToLower(policies.Policies[i].PolicyId) {
            c.sendResultDialog(TestFoundPolicy, c.name, policies.Policies[i].PolicyId, policies.Policies[i].PolicyDescription)
            return true
        } else {
            c.sendResultDialog(PolicyNotFound, c.name)
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because your loop body returns.

Comment: This always returns on the first iteration of the loop, so any code after this loop is unreachable. You probably meant to have `PolicyNotFound` handled after the loop, but we can't tell for certain without a complete example.

Answer (score 2):

Since, you call return inside the for loop, you are not iterating over all the slice values.
You would probably do this

```golang
policy_found := false
for i := 0; i < len(policies.Policies); i++ {
    if strings.ToLower(c.name) == strings.ToLower(policies.Policies[i].PolicyName) || strings.ToLower(c.name) == strings.ToLower(policies.Policies[i].PolicyId) {
            c.sendResultDialog(TestFoundPolicy, c.name, policies.Policies[i].PolicyId, policies.Policies[i].PolicyDescription)
        policy_found = true
    }
}
if !policy_found {
    c.sendResultDialog(PolicyNotFound, c.name)
}
return policy_found
```

this should fix your bug

Comment: your code will overwrite the `policy_found` value every iteration. You could do something like `policy_found = policy_found || false`, but the `else` clause should probably not be in the loop at all.

Comment: thanks @JimB !! updated accordingly

Answer (score 2):

This is hard to tell without a full example (no idea what sendResultDialog is doing). But the error is likely due to the fact that you're returning from within a loop, you can try something like this instead:

```
policyFound := false

for i := 0; i < len(policies.Policies); i++ {
    if strings.ToLower(c.name) == strings.ToLower(policies.Policies[i].PolicyName) || strings.ToLower(c.name) == strings.ToLower(policies.Policies[i].PolicyId) {
        c.sendResultDialog(TestFoundPolicy, c.name, policies.Policies[i].PolicyId, policies.Policies[i].PolicyDescription)
        policyFound = true

        break // remove this if you want to call sendResultDialog for all entries and not just the first one
    }
}

if !policyFound {
    c.sendResultDialog(PolicyNotFound, c.name)
}

return policyFound
```

Comment: just noticed this is quite similar to @abhinava-b-n answer, with the added break and removed the redundant policy_found = false part